# date start of submodule with commit number in github and installable git server

Tags: github, git-submodules

Whenever I used a git submodule the commit number was not shown. Now it is shown. From when and which version did github/ git server start using a commit number in the submodules.

[image: submodules without commit number]

[image: submodules with commit number]

Comment: This display is completely up to GitHub, but as far as I know they've always shown the `@ <hash>` part *if* there's a `.gitmodules` entry. Certainly they were showing those `@ <hash>` suffixes back in 2017 or so. Note that in your two images, the one that doesn't have `@ <hash>` also doesn't have a `.gitmodules` file.

Comment: ok. i thought it was in this couple of months or last month they started it. internet is so much date manipulated. but since it is git or github, I can trust - hopefully